# How to export cookies/session from Mechanize to Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, testing, web-scraping, mechanize

I am using website that have no API so I decided to call actions from webside by Selenium.
When I use selenium server, login will fail because of catcha so I decided to go login via Mechanize and then continue with Selenium since buttons or webside are generated by JS.
Is it possible to move active session generated by Mechanize and store it to Selenium so there wont be any login window anymore?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of python mechanize, try using ruby mechanize gem to get and store cookie values to file. Much easier to use.
Use Chrome>developer tools>application to view cookies for logged in user. Determine minimum necessary cookies requirements by clicking on and deleting arbitrary cookies then refreshing to see if still logged in. Example:

```
require 'mechanize'
mechanize = Mechanize.new
page = mechanize.get(<somesite>)
page.forms[0].fields[0].value = <username>
page.forms[0].fields[1].value = <password>
page.forms[0].submit
mechanize.cookies[0].value 
File.write("cookie.txt", mechanize.cookies[0].value)
```